# Add Custom values to build.gradle file via build-extras.gradle in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I had updated cordova-android version to 6.4.0 and before that I had 5.1.1 installed. Here the problem was that when updated to 6.4.0 version, while building the project I was getting error. So to overcome that issue I had to add the below code

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        }
}
```

Now the problem is every time I build the project I have to edit build.gradle file, which is generated while adding the platform to the project in Cordova. As this is not part of Source Control.

To overcome this I have used the solution from this [post](https://gist.github.com/charlesbedrosian/8a33c866704ff51ab5700b272b7cf150). Here I am adding the Javascript file and adding the hook in the config.xml

Java script file

```
var fs = require('fs');
var rootdir = process.argv[2];

var android_dir = rootdir + '/platforms/android';
var gradle_file = rootdir + '/build-extras.gradle';
var dest_gradle_file = android_dir + '/build-extras.gradle';

if (fs.existsSync(android_dir) && fs.existsSync(gradle_file)) {
    console.log('Copy ' + gradle_file + ' to ' + android_dir); 
    fs.createReadStream(gradle_file).pipe(fs.createWriteStream (dest_gradle_file));
} else {
    console.log(gradle_file + ' not found. Skipping');
}
```

Build-extras.gradle

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
android {
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hooks in Config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <hook src="scripts/buildGradleHook.js" type="before_build" />
</platform>
```

The hooks added is not reflecting in the generated android folder. That is build-extras.gradle file is not reflected in android folder.

Comment: You shouldn't need the javascript or config.xml file changes.  If your environment is set up properly, all you should have to do is drop the `build-extras.gradle` in your `platforms/android` directory and the rest should take care of itself.  You should also only need the `configurations.all` block

Comment: @BShaps :Here the problem of adding build-extras.gradle file under platforms/android is, when platform android is deleted I will loose the build-extras.gradle file as this is not part of source control.

Comment: Just keep the file somewhere and add it back when you delete/add the platform.  If it is a big deal you can create a simple script to run the platform add and copy the build-extras.gradle file.  You shouldn't need to delete the platform on a regular basis.

Comment: @BShaps Copying back build-extras.gradle file is not the issue. The issue is when I build the project with new build-extras.gradle file **(as mentioned above)** throws below error `1: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ?ext
  . At [1:1]  @ line 1, column 1.
     ?ext.postBuildExtras = {
     ^` . Do you have any **idea on this? Is build-extras.gradle file proper**.

Comment: remove the `ext.postBuildExtras` and `android` blocks and only include the `configurations.all` block.  No idea why it thinks the first char is a ?

Comment: @BShaps I tried that also I get a similar error `1: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ?configurations
  . At [1:1]  @ line 1, column 1.
     ?configurations.all {
     ^` like this. I have a doubt on the syntax as to what I have added is correct, because if I directly add the above mentioned first code directly to build.gradle file it works.

Comment: No idea why that would happen, it might be worth trying from a fresh cordova project if you can't figure out that error.

Comment: @BShaps As you said I created a new cordova project and added only the javascript file and updated the hoos in config.xml. But still find the same error. Is there any syntax for writing code in buid-extras.gradle file ?

Comment: Oh, don't include the hooks in config.xml or the javascript file, you don't have to include the build-extras.gradle yourself.  It should all be handled for you when you build.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your solution and found that the vars declared to define the different paths are wrong.

I changed your hook code for this:

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {
    var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
    path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path'),
    rootdir = ctx.opts.projectRoot,
    android_dir = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android');
    gradle_file = rootdir + '/build-extras.gradle';
    dest_gradle_file = android_dir + '/build-extras.gradle';

    /*
    console.log("Before-Build Hook - rootdir", rootdir);
    console.log("Before-Build Hook - android_dir", android_dir);
    console.log("Before-Build Hook - gradle_file", gradle_file);
    console.log("Before-Build Hook - dest_gradle_file", dest_gradle_file);
    */

    if(!fs.existsSync(gradle_file)){
        console.log(gradle_file + ' not found. Skipping');
        return;
    }else if(!fs.existsSync(android_dir)){
        console.log(android_dir + ' not found. Skipping');
       return;
    }

    console.log('Copy ' + gradle_file + ' to ' + android_dir);
    fs.createReadStream(gradle_file).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest_gradle_file));
}
```

Also, in the Hook doc says it must be executable, so it needs to be wrapped by " module.exports = function(ctx) {  }".

Comment: visit "https://gist.github.com/charlesbedrosian/8a33c866704ff51ab5700b272b7cf150"