# Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

My project was working fine yesterday and today i'm getting the error below. please Help.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.aar

Comment: maybe you are change something in your gradle file.share it if you can

Comment: app.gradle or build.gradle ????

Comment: build.gradle Module app

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {

        
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="25.0.2"
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=26 
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=26 
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: is there a better way I can send it through???

Comment: try this allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven { url "maven.google.com" }
    jcenter()
  }
}

Comment: Thanks a lot Ghost. That did the trick. how does one up vote this answer???

Comment: It's a pain to manually update build.gradle files since cordova steps on those.  Check this for other options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485267/6599076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80362794
Looks like known issue for jcenter

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you update your gradle recently? I've been also getting some strange issues there. Try to change the distribution url in your gradle-wrapper.properties file. Try this: 
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

Comment: Unzipping C:\Users\MXXM\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip to C:\Users\MXXM\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Comment: I have the same issue and did not update gradle. At 8am EST we had a Jenkins build pass, and at 3PM EST, the same branch failed. So in the 7 hour period it appears this kicked up again.