# Ionic - Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic project that after upgrading to OSx Mojave, for some reason is not building anymore.

The project is built over Ionic 3.

I have Cordova CLI 7.0.0

When I run

```
ionic cordova run android
```

I get this error when trying to build:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.aar
```

I tried changing build.gradle, downgrading cordova, upgrading cordova, tried with different android versions, but still the same issue.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 3 Android Build Error (could not find support-v4.jar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451055/ionic-3-android-build-error-could-not-find-support-v4-jar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently not really sure what causes the issue but here's what helped me:

Look inside you **build.gradle** files under platforms/android and platforms/android/app and move jcenter() dependency to the bottom of the repositories.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and fixed by workaround below. That works for me. 
Change following lines in the file **project.properties** from your_project_folder\platforms\android

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue yesterday...

I do following changes in my build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Just added jcenter() below maven

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with ionic 5 - cordova, and I have sloved this by remove this line **implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"** in **build.gradle(Module:android.app) > dependencies**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
//implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).